# Can't figure out how to connect to Bitnami Subversion VM on Windows Azure using SSH

Tags: svn, azure, ssh, bitnami

I installed Bitnami Subversion VM to Windows Azure

When I try to connect using PuTTY, I'm getting  "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)"

As I understand, i need to connect using public key.

But so far I can't figure out how to either upload key to VM, or download key from VM.

Edit:
Looks like I made several newbie mistakes. Here is the key points:

1. When you use script from VMDepot, not Web UI, as i did, you have to include your ssh public key to the script. For some reason VMDepot script omit that information.
2. UserId and Password in VMDepot script are your Linux UserId/password, not Azure's
3. Make sure you don't specify -P setting (remove password) - in this case you'll not be able to run sudo commands.

Other then that, everything works!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like initial configuration expects you to login with a username and pw/key you chose during setup:

- The [Bitnamic Subversion on Azure page](http://bitnami.com/stack/subversion/cloud/azure) indicates the the username to use is `bitnami`.
- It also has a link to a page entitled ["How to connect to my (Windows Azure) server"](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Azure_Cloud/Servers) which says:

  > Enter your login and password that you already configured from the Azure wizard. The example below shows "bitnami" user but your user could be different.
- That references the "Azure wizard"; there's another link to ["Azure Cloud - Getting Started"](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Azure_Cloud/Getting_Started) that has a screen shot like this:

  [image: screen shot from vm config]

Note particularly the option to `Upload ssh key for authentication`